# Run Qt app with eglfs plugin on a normal computer

Tags: qt, plugins, drm, eglfs

I am trying to run a Qt application under EGLFS with Linux Mint on a Macbook Pro.

I have:

1. Configured and compiled Qt with all the needed flags and dependences.
2. Tried to run the app with X11 turned off.
3. Used kms integration.
4. Installed all the Mesa drivers ( I have an intel GPU ).
5. Even compiled EGL myself.

But it keeps saying "Unable to create EGL Display".
Does anyone knows what am I missing ?

P.S For example I can run weston-launch which I believe it runs over drm-egl.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like you. I have solved it by:

1. Building Qt with "-opengl desktop" switch.
2. Making conf file with my displays (look at: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html at section "eglfs with eglfs_kms backend") inside application directory
3. Exporting QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG=conf

Then switch to free tty and run application with -platform eglfs argument.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you say, but it still says **_Failed to load EGL device integration "elgfs_kms"_** . My config file looks like this `{
  "device": "/dev/dri/card0",
  "hwcursor": true,
  "pbuffers": true,
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "VGA",
      "mode": "1024x768"
    },
    {
      "name": "HDMI1",
      "mode": "1024x768"
    }
  ]
}` Any idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: I compiled Qt again with drm enabled, and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to the Qt lib directory on the new tty and now it works!

Comment: hi, @ehopperdietzel. Can you clarify me how did you enable drm or kms when you compiled Qt again? seems that I don't have the "eglfs_kms" device integration plugin. thank you in advance.